# Drupal fails to redirect

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

So I'm having a bit of a problem with my drupal site. I set it up on my localhost and it was working fine. Then I upload everything to a server. And now most of my page works fine, but some redirects fails. Like when I'm registered and i press logout it goes to mypage/logout, but there it remains with blank page. Same think happens when i try to search. It just loads blank page. But if i go to mypagae/node/search-term it works. Any idea what i may try? If it's any help here is my site: http://staging.bringler.com/.

Btw. I tryied turning on error reporting with adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

in index.php but no effect.

edit: I also checked error logs in apache but found nothing unusual...

edit2: I notice that there is sometimes a problem with something like that:

```
warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/bringler/modules/menu/menu.module:1) in /var/www/bringler/includes/common.inc on line 153.
```

I offten see warnings like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW i found a solution!

The problem was that i didnt have

```
;output_buffering = On
```

uncommented on server. So i added

```
<?php
ob_start(); ?>
```

to bootstrap.inc and now all works! Epic!